# silverlight popup is not visible

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, popup, controls

I have the following defined in xaml:

```
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Popup Visibility="Visible">
                        <TextBlock Name="myPopupText">Popup Text</TextBlock>
                </Popup>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

But I can't see the popup, if I remove the popup part:

```
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Name="myPopupText">Popup Text</TextBlock>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

I can see the text box.

Any ideas why the popup box isn't visible?

Comment: How are you using the Popup? Where's your code / xaml that tells it to open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have

```
<Popup IsOpen="True" ... />
```